# How can I install an activity with my widget?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have created a widget, but I'd like to add an activity to be installed in the phone as well, like a configuration screen, what's the best method to accomplish that with a widget? thanks!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

Comment: I understand that this activity is going to be launched right when you create the widget, but I need an activity that I can access anytime without having to re-create to setup an alarm, which is an extra feature in the widget, does it work for my approach?

Comment: You are welcome to add an appropriate `<intent-filter>` to have your activity be in the `LAUNCHER`. Or, set up another activity that will be your `LAUNCHER` activity.

Comment: It was my bad, I just added the intent-filter like I do with a non-widget activity, and it worked great, thanks! how do I set your comment as answer? I don't see the option.

Answer (score 0):

> I need an activity that I can access anytime without having to re-create to setup an alarm, which is an extra feature in the widget, does it work for my approach?

In addition to [setting up your activity to be a configuration activity for the app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring), you can include other `<intent-filter>` elements as needed in your manifest for other scenarios, such as the standard `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` to make the activity appear in home screen launchers.

Just beware that these activities are started in different ways, and so you may wish to use `getIntent()` and examine how your activity was launched to adjust your behavior accordingly.